# How to change app ID in buildfire.js

Tags: buildfire

I'm working on 3 apps simultaneously. When I login in:
 "https://dev.buildfire.com",

only one of the app's ID appears.

How can I login with another app ID?

Comment: please be specific. add more details.

Answer (score 0):

The website **dev.buildfire.com**, aka the "developer portal", is used to manage your custom developed plugins. Alternatively **app.buildfire.com**, aka the "control panel", is what you use to manage your apps. If you want to manage your apps just login into the control panel and select which ever app you like.

It might help if you describe what specifically you are trying to do.

Comment: thank you very much. my problem: when I upload my plugins in "https://dev.buildfire.com/#/", I can add these plugins to only one of my designed apps. the ID of this app appears on the top right side of the page "https://dev.buildfire.com/#/". I cannot change this app ID.

Comment: By default, your custom plugins are made available to your test app. Generally speaking if you want to add your plugin to other apps, including your own, you need to submit your plugin to the marketplace. This makes your plugin available to everyone, not just yourself.

Comment: thanks, attila. I've just started learning mobile app developing. I need a free mobile app development platform. Biuldfire is not free. can you recommend me a free good mobile app development platform for android and ios.

Comment: I believe BuildFire is free up right up until the point where you submit an app to the app stores. You can still develop and preview your apps for free up until that point. That includes previewing the app on an actual device.

I'm not an expert in the various mobile app platforms, but I believe they will all require some sort of free if you want to publish an app to the app stores.